# Test if Has One Relationship has Changed in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to have a 'before_save' callback that detects if a 'has_one' relationship has changed (the relationship **not** the model at the end of the relationship)? For example, something that would act like this:

```
@person.picture = @picture
@person.picture_changed? # true
@person.save
@person.picture_changed? # false
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try `relation.changed?`... You may also want to look into observers, depending on what you are trying to accomblish.

Example:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :relation
  before_save :check_relation_changed
  private def check_relation_changed
    do_something if relation.changed?
  end
end
```

Ref: http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/3/31/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-dirty-objects

Comment: Sorry, what I meant with the above is to detect if the relationship changes, not if the model at the end of the relationship changes. I've added an example above.

Comment: Hmm well, answer was accepted anyway... Or does that indeed detect changes to the relation linking instead of relation contents?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it works with

`@person.picture_id_changed?`

Comment: it would be `picture.changed?` but I didn't find a way to know if the association is a different model

Comment: There is no foreign key with an `has_one`, the foreign key would be `picture.person_id`