# Rails has_one: check if new association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a following `Project` model:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :manager,
             class_name: 'User'

  has_many :memberships,
           dependent: :destroy

  has_one :technician_membership, -> { technicians }, class_name: 'Membership'
  has_one :technician, through: :technician_membership, class_name: 'User', source: :user

  (...)
end
```

I would like to create a notification if a new technician is assigned to a project. What I'm struggling with is knowing whether or not a technician changed on save.

I was hoping [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001873/test-if-has-one-relationship-has-changed-in-rails) would solve my problem but unfortunately it doesn't.

```
project.technician
=> nil
project.technician = User.find 4
=> #<User id: 4, ...>
project.technician.changed?
=> false
project.technician_changed?
=> false
```

What would be the best way to check if an association was created / updated?

Comment: have you tried `technician_id_changed`?

Comment: @LeninRajRajasekaran I did. It returns a NoMethodError (`NoMethodError (undefined method 'technician_id_changed?' for #<Project:0x00007f7fef6678f0>)`)

Comment: You can use [association callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks).

Comment: `project.technician.changed?` does not work since you are calling `.changed?` on the technician instance - not an attribute of `project`. `technician_id_changed` would only work if you had a `belongs_to` association with a technician_id column on the projects table.

Answer (score 0):

What about catch this in technician_membership model and use `before_save` method?

**technician_membership.rb**

```
before_save :check_new_assignation

def check_new_assignation
  if project_id.changed?
    send_notification
  end
end
```